# How can I page up or down in tmux with Terminal.app?

Tags: ssh, tmux, terminal.app

When I am in `tmux` only a portion of the text shows up. If I try to scroll up or down the console scrolls up **but not the actual text**. If I do CTRL+b followed by `[`, I see in the status bar `*tmux`, and If I press the up or down arrow I can actually go up/down on the text *line by line*. When I press `q` I see in the status line `bash`.

When I do `CTRL+b` follow `Page UP` or `Page` the console goes up or down but not the text.

How can I scroll up or down the text in more than one line at a time?

Comment: What I was surprised about, but what seems to work out-of-the-box, is scrolling with the middle mouse while using tmux within gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 116):

If you're using OS X's Terminal.app, it will capture <kbd>Page up/down</kbd> keypresses and just scroll the window contents, as if you used the scroll bar. You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page up/down</kbd> to send them to the application inside the terminal.

Using that, you should be able to scroll by a page at a time using:

1. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
2. <kbd>[</kbd>
3. Arrows keys or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page up/down</kbd>
4. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when done with scrollback

If you want to change this to behave like every other terminal app on every other platform, you can go to Terminal -> Preferences, Settings, choose your profile and go to Keyboard, and swap the bindings for "page down/page up" and "shift page down/shift page up":

[image: Terminal.app keyboard settings screenshot]

Comment: +1 although I can not test it but it seems to be a winner answer.I remember trying `CMD` with arrows but I don't remember trying `SHIFT`. Also `swap the bindings for "page down/page up" and "shift page down/shift page up` what do you mean? I am not sure what to do. I really hope this works because my nerves are completely wrecked by these

Comment: @Jim Take a look at the screenshot. If you open the settings on your computer, you'll see that your "page up/down" and "shift page up/down" keys have different actions than what I have (these are the bindings: which key does which action). If you switch them around, you can change what happens when you're holding shift or not holding shift. (If you're editing them, you can input `\033` by pressing escape)

Comment: I don't have my `mac` available to check this right now, but in your screenshot for `shift page down` it has a text i.e.`scroll to next page in buffer`. This is special text that does exactly what is says? I.e. defines some mapping? Also is there a good book about these in mac? Because I have been going crazy with the keyboard the past weeks

Comment: @Jim I don't know any books; I'm just surrounded by people raised on Macs. As for the key settings, it'll make more sense once you're actually doing it. :)

Comment: Ok. I will try this asap. Thank you for your answer. I feel positive that you have given my the solution to my problem!!!Will accept this as soon as I test this

Comment: This turns out **not** to be the answer but it help me figure out somehow the problem. I looked into my settings and they were actually the way you specify to change the to i.e. the settings were already swapped. That surprised me as neither `SHIFT+PageUP` nor `PageUP` or `CTRL-PageUP` worked. **But** I was using `Pro` while in your screenshot you show `Basic`. So I switched to `Basic` and the keys are indeed reversed, but without changing them and using `SHIFT-PageUP` I am actually able to scroll up! How is this possible? Is `Pro` messed up or something?

Comment: Worked for me. Also `Esc` seems to cancel scrolling same way as `Ctrl+C`

Comment: Thanks man! Don't know where did you get this but it works!

Answer (score 44):

I use the default combination on pre Yosemite MacBook Pro: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>.

**EDIT:** I've found on a MBP running Yosemite <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> should works by default.

In documentation it is often shown as ⇞ or ⇟

Comment: This works for me on a new Air with 10.9.4 without changing any preferences or config files or running any commands.

Comment: +1 for the EDIT. function + arrow key is simple and set by default.

Comment: +1 for the EDIT. function + arrow key is simple and set by default.

Answer (score 21):

Edit the ~/.tmux.conf file, insert the setting 'mouse', and source the file i.e:

```
###Find tmux version first:
tmux -V
> 1.8 

###For tmux version 1.8;
vim ~/.tmux.conf ### file
set -g mode-mouse on  ### Edit the .tmux.conf file with this setting
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf

###For tmux 2.1 version on:
vim ~/.tmux.conf ### file
set -g mouse on ### Edit the .tmux.conf file with this setting
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Comment: This works perfectly!

Comment: 'set -g mode-mouse on'
setting this worked for me.
can you explain more why

Answer (score 9):

An update of binding commands in Rob's answer, and in response to Alex's comments:

I also found `page-up` and `page-down` are not valid tmux (v1.8) commands, a correct way of updating your `~/.tmux.conf` is:

```
bind-key -t (emacs|vi)-copy j page-up
bind-key -t (emacs|vi)-copy ; page-down
```

Pick either emacs or vi depending on what style tmux uses, refer to `mode-keys` in [tmux manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1)

After this you can pageup and down with `j` and `;` in copy-mode

Comment: Quick link on how to put tmux into vi mode http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vi-mode-in-tmux/

Comment: If you read the [article](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/vi-mode-in-tmux/) posted by JiminyCricket carefully, it is explained that the syntax above is only for tmux version 2.3 and below.  If you have a newer version, then after enabling vi mode, the command `list-keys -T copy-mode-vi` will show key bindings in the new syntax (good examples to follow).  If you want to create a page-up binding, for example, then use the line `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi j           send-keys -X page-up`

Answer (score 3):

From https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux

> If you have issues scrolling with Shift-PageUp/Shift-PageDown in your
>   terminal, try this:
>
> set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'

It could also be a terminal emulation thing, try one of the following.

```
export TERM=vt100
export TERM=ansi
export TERM=xterm
```

maybe one of those would do it.

There's also bind-key, in `~/.tmux.conf`

```
bind-key j page-up
bind-key ; page-down
```

would bind <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd> to previous and next.

Comment: `page-up` and `page-down` are not valid tmux (v1.8) commands, so those last two commands give an error: `Unknown command: page-(up|down)`

Comment: See Ronnie's answer below to get page-up and page-down working

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure you are using the proper tmux key bindings (vi vs emacs) by trying both sets: https://superuser.com/questions/196060/selecting-text-tmux-copy-mode

I had a similar issue where I could move the cursor with arrow keys but couldn't page up or down using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd> and couldn't select and copy using <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Turns out, tmux was on emacs mode on my Mac and vi mode in Linux even though I never explicitly set it for either OS.

Comment: Thanks for this; didn't realize Ctrl+U/D were available; I guess that's part of tmux vi mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to OS X and are familiar with Windows and Linux keyboard shortcuts, you will probably be in the habit of using the `CTRL` for many things. In OS X the Command (aka Apple) Key is often used in place of the `CTRL` key.

Also, instead of the Page keys, try using `Command + Up` (or the other directional keys) to move your cursor or screen.