# How can I create a shortcut to resize panes in a tmux window?

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, tmux, macos

I am having [lots of issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81540/can-not-scroll-up-or-down-in-tmux/81549#81549) with `tmux` on Mac.

One problem I have is that I cannot bind a key in my `tmux.conf` to resize my panes.

What I need is the `CTRL-b: resize-pane -U 10`. I'm trying to increase the size of the pane upwards ten cells (or downwards or left or right) using a key shortcut instead of having to type this over and over (which I currently do unfortunately).

But I cannot find a way to configure this since on Mac, it seems that `CTRL` and other keys work differently on Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind e resize-pane -U 10
```

Then, `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`. (another useful shortcut: use the same principle).

Comment: 1) So `bind e resize-pane -U 10` is one line in `tmux` that binds the key `e` with the resize? Should I have pressed the `ctrl-b` before `e`? 2) I am not sure what you mean with `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`. Doesn't `tmux` read the home directory's conf file?

Comment: @Jim: Yes, you hit the prefix key first. Then `e`. Yes, `tmux` does that, but it is faster to have it as a shortcut as well, so you don't have to restart `tmux` every time you make an improvement/extension in/to the init file.

Comment: So `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` is another line in `tmux.conf`?

Comment: @Jim: No, that would be something you type. In the init file, it could look like this: `bind u source-file ~/.tmux.conf` if you want this for `u`.

Comment: @Jim: It works, and now that you know the principle, setup a bunch of shortcuts to do all sorts of stuff. Don't be too careful, just try stuff you think will work.

Comment: BTW if you have spare time please check out this one in case you can figure this out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81796/vim-and-tmux-are-conflicting-how-can-i-fix-this

Comment: why are you using `bind` and not `bind-key`?

Answer (score 13):

Below are my keybindings that let me resize a pane.

It uses <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>direction</kbd>, where the keys for the directions are the same as in Vim:

```
  k
h l
  j
```

```
# Resize the current pane using Alt + direction
bind -n M-k resize-pane -U 5
bind -n M-j resize-pane -D 5
bind -n M-h resize-pane -L 5
bind -n M-l resize-pane -R 5
```

Answer (score 4):

There is already a shortcut: Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, press <kbd>b</kbd> and then adjust the size with <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd> etc. without releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Also, with

```
set -g mouse on
```

in `~/.tmux.conf` you do it with the mouse. But with this setting active you need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to do selections and paste with the scroll wheel.

Comment: doesnt work on mac unfortunately as ctrl+direction brings up mac window switcher

Comment: Hey @JimmyMGLim , if you want you can disable ctrl+arrows shortcuts on MacOS: go to "Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcut -> Mission Control" and remove the checks on all four ctrl+arrow lines. I did it (I don't use those OS shortcuts anyway) and it works great. :)

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18043/how-can-i-make-ctrlright-left-arrow-stop-changing-desktops-in-lion

Comment: Is there a way to make this faster? this approach takes forever to make big adjustments.

Comment: @azizj1 I updated the answer.