# vim and tmux are conflicting. How can I fix this?

Tags: linux, ssh, vim, tmux, vimrc

I'm having a painful experience with `tmux`.  I'm using `solarized` in `vim` but when I run `tmux` then my `vim` configuration does not work. It's as if `solarized` is not configured in my `.vimrc`.

Out of `tmux` all is fine! Using `tmux` using `vim` hurts my sight....

What do I need to do?

Comment: What is $TERM setting in and out of tmux?

Comment: @jasonwryan: I did not set a `$TERM` for `tmux` if this is what you are asking me. I think `$TERM` outside of `tmux` is not set. But can not check this right now unfortunatelly

Comment: @jasonwryan:But I have set this in `.vimrc`: `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`

Comment: `echo $TERM` in and out of tmux and edit the results into your question. This is almost always a result of not using the correct $TERM in tmux. See the [first point in the FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/FAQ).

Comment: @jasonwryan:You were right.I fixed the `$TERM`.But now it seems to pick up solarized partly.I.e. it displays with solarized colors only the specific lines.Outside of the lines/letters I get the color of terminal.It is a mess. Like the text is in some white background

Comment: @jasonwryan: Now it is `xterm-256color` inside and outside `tmux`

Comment: Change it to `screen-256color` in tmux as per the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting `tmux` with `tmux -2`