# How can I bind my ctrl+b so that I don't need to press it to resize my pane?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I managed to be able to resize panes in tmux thanks to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81782/how-can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-resize-panes-in-a-tmux-window).
But now I press `CTRL-b` and then `e` each time I want to resize the pane (e.g. make larger to the left).
How could I bind the `CTRL-b` as well so I only press a single key e.g. just `e` and resize the pane (instead of pressing `CTRL-b` and then `e`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not really make sense to bind the command prefix to another key in such a way that it goes away (changing the prefix, however, is common; many people prefer `C-a`). The whole point of the prefix is to let tmux know the next key sequence you enter is intended for tmux and not the program open in the tmux pane.

So if you were able to bind `C-b e` to the `e` key, you would then not be able to type `e` when providing normal input to whatever programs are open in your tmux panes.

Comment: So the fastest pace I can do this is: `CTRL-b` and then `e`?

Comment: `C-a` I assume you mean `SHIFT-c a`. Why not just `c` instead of `Shift-c`?

Comment: No, the big C refers to the Ctrl key. It is a command shorthand. For me, I prefer `C-a` for my command prefix. Feels faster. You can change it to control a using this command `set-option -g prefix C-a
`

Comment: The shorthand is explained here: http://www.cs.vassar.edu/sysnews/emacs_tips#emacs_command_shorthand